# Segmentation fault (core dumped) while retrieving bytes from aerospike

Tags: aerospike

I am using Aerospike 3.5.4 with python client 1.0.38.
My intention is to store and retrieve Float values into Aerospike using this python client as Float Data Types are not supported by Aerospike natively. From the below code snippet, I am able to insert the float converted to binary data into Aerospike but while retrieving I am getting Segmentation fault (core dumped).

```
import aerospike
import struct
aerospike_config = {
  'hosts': [('localhost', 3000), ],
}
obj  = aerospike.client(aerospike_config).connect()
key = ('my_namespace', 'my_set', 59)
f = struct.pack('f', 20.6)
obj.put(key, {'price':f})
print struct.unpack('f', obj.get(key))
```

On checking the data using aql, it looks like below.

```
aql> select * from my_namespace.my_set where PK=59
```

+--------+
| price  |
+--------+
| "�̤A" |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.001 secs)

Please Help.

Comment: I don't know much about aerospike, but pushing arbitrary binary down the throat of a system isn't very likely to succeed. According to the documentation, aerospike *does* support binary data, but it needs to be fixed-size. So I guess the question is: how do you specify the value's type?

Comment: the segfault is on the server or on the client? Can you please post the segfault trace?

Comment: Bugs aren't a stackoverflow question. Open a new issue on the GitHub repo. FYI 1.0.39 should address serialization.

Comment: Thanks Ronen for your valuable reply. Opened an issue on github. I think its worth for me to wait for 1.0.39.

Comment: This has been fixed in python client release 1.0.40 by RBotzer.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in Aerospike Python client release 1.0.40, which included the following features:

- Enhanced automatic serialization of unsupported types using cPickle.
- Support for user-provided serializer/deserializer methods as an alternative to automatic serialization.